# How can a long Python list be checked and repaired?

Tags: python, list, validation

I have a Python list that is generated automatically. It is of the following form:

```
[(186, 25, 192, 255), (184, 25, 192, 255), (184, 27, 193, 255), (184, 29, 193, 255), (184, 31, 193, 255), (183, 32, 192, 255), (182, 33, 191, 255), ... many further elements... ]
```

It is a very long list that is solely contained in a file of about 100 MB. It is possible that this list is malformed in some way. I want to detect where exactly it is malformed so that it can be repaired by replacing any problematic elements with `(0, 0, 0, 255)`.

I have edited the file such that it contains the following:

```
list1 = [(186, 25, 192, 255), ... many further elements...
print("list length: {length}".format(length = len(list1)))
```

When I run the file through Python, the full list prints, followed by a lot of whitespace, followed by the error message "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" with a caret pointing at the whitespace.

Because the list is so long, a programmatic approach is needed for validating the list and repairing it. What would be a good way to do this?

Comment: Looks like a bunch of pixels. I wonder why it isn't stored in a image. How is the list malformed? It contains some invalid syntax?

Comment: Don't know, if there's a limit in Code-Size. But why don't you save the numbers not in a csv-file?

Comment: So you're saying the list is given as a string, right?

Comment: So your file contains a dumped "list" with parens, commas etc. as you show? Are there any newlines?

Comment: Can you produce a sample snippet per [ask]?

Comment: Also, what operating system are you on? This would be easier to do as a Unix one-liner

Comment: @nneonneo Hi there. As described in the question, an error is reported, but I don't know what is wrong because the list is so long that it amounts to a 100 MB file. I need to find this out automatically. The format is what it is because it was generated by a machine learning algorithm and I needed a format that would be fairly easy to repair.

Comment: @Falko Right now, I have a file that contains a list in Python form. I could add code around this to make it a string, but at present I have simply set it equal to a variable, as shown in the question.

Comment: @boardrider The list is 100 MB. This means that I can neither include it in the question nor can I parse it manually to find examples of where it may be malformatted. The question is really about how I could do this automatically.

Comment: @alexis I'm on Linux. Passing the list through SEd us not a bad idea. I'm not sure how to do it, but it may be doable.

Comment: It would have been `sed` to add some badly needed newlines, then `grep -v` to find lines that don't match the regexp I used in my answer (plus parens).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a really unfortunate format that your data is dumped in; I assume the intent is to evaluate it on reading into python, which is a terrible approach (you're seeing one reason right now).

Supposing you don't have access to the Unix tools that would make it trivial to check the file's syntax, the way to do it in python is to check the tuples (or rather, the strings representing them) one at a time. Since it seems there aren't any newlines, you'll have to read the whole thing at once and split it yourself:

```
import re
with open("datadump.txt") as fp:
    text = fp.read()
parts = text[2:-2].split("), (")
for n, part in enumerate(parts):
    if not re.match(r"^\d+, \d+, \d+, \d+$", part):
        print("The %d-th tuple is malformed: %s" % (n, part))
```

You may get spurious messages at the first and last tuple if the whitespace doesn't quite match my assumptions (e.g., that should have been `text[2:-3]` if there's a newline at the end of the file), but it should be enough to point you to the problem.

**PS.** FWIW, a better format would have been to just print out the numbers four to a line, without any decoration:

```
186 25 192 255
184 25 192 255
184 27 193 255
etc.
```

It takes a couple of lines of code to write out and read back in, but it's much nicer to work with in the long run-- and you could have easily read and validated lines one at a time.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and for your clear explanations! That worked perfectly! :) The data was created by a machine learning algorithm and I needed some format what was simple in form both for the purposes of training the algorithm and for repairing the output, so I went with the simple listing of pixels. Fortunately, there were only 5 minor mistakes that the algorithm made in the whole thing.

Comment: Glad it worked. I added a note with what I would have used.